# How to add space between an image and a button used with routerLink in CSS

Tags: css, angular

I used a routerLink with an image and a button to redirect, respectively, to the home and to the addition of a customer.

Now would I like to set a space between these? I used "&nbsp" but I would like to do it with CSS.

How can I set CSS to have space between them?

```js
<a routerLink=""><img src="https://secureservercdn.net/45.40.150.47/f52.661.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/neon_blue__home_button_ico-copy.png?time=1624440065" width="100" height="100"></a>  &nbsp;
      <a routerLink="/add-customer"><button class="btn btn-secondary">Add customer</button></a>
```

Comment: use CSS for this. `a {margin-left: 200px}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be slight overkill but if you wrap it in a containing `<div>` you can align and space the elements with a CSS `grid` display:  I added a border for visual clarity only

```css
.my-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  column-gap: 1rem;
}

.my-container a {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <a routerLink="" class="router-link"><img src="https://secureservercdn.net/45.40.150.47/f52.661.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/neon_blue__home_button_ico-copy.png?time=1624440065" width="100" height="100"></a>
  <a routerLink="/add-customer" class="router-link"><button class="btn btn-secondary">Add customer</button></a>
</div>
```